# Generating function for the characteristic function of prime numbers

Tags: nt.number-theory, prime-numbers, generating-functions

What do we know about the generating function of $\chi(n)$ ([A010051](http://oeis.org/A010051))
$$
  f(x) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \chi(n)x^n = \sum_{p\text{ prime}} x^p
$$
for $\chi(n)$ the characteristic function of the primes:

$$
  \chi(n) = 
     \begin{cases}
        1, & \text{if $n$ is prime}\\
        0, & \text{otherwise}
     \end{cases}
$$
Are there some references I could take a look at?

Comment: Depends on what you're looking for.  For example, if $0<x<1$ you can write $\int_1^{\infty} \pi(t) x^t dt = f(x)/(-\log x)$ and so you can understand $f(x)$ by putting in information on $\pi(t)$.

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/602706/generating-function-for-the-characteristic-function-of-primes for answers.